# Imposing a hierarchical structure on relational data

Tags: xpath, data-structures, hierarchical

I'm trying to invent a syntax for imposing a hierarchy on relational data.  (I'm currently using a relational database to store it, but that's not particularly relevant to the question.) The example I'm using is the [Fédération Cynologique Internationale](http://www.fci.be/en/nomenclature/) (World Canine Organisation), which lists dog breeds. They data is organized as follows:

- The basic unit is a breed. A breed has:

  - One of ten groups
  - A section within the group (groups have zero to five sections)
  - An optional subsection within the section
  - An optional set of varieties
  - A set of (one to two) places of origin
- Variety has an optional set of subvarieties

I'd like to be able to express any "reasonable" structure in which to place the breeds. Here are some examples using a regex-based syntax, with the following interpretations:

1. Full structure

   /group/(section/(subsection/)?)?place/breed(/variety(/subvariety)?)?

   - The top level of the structure is group
   - Sections are at the next level, if the group has any
   - If the group contains subsections, these are the next level of the hierarchy
   - Places are next, within group, section or subsection, depending on the structure
   - Breeds are organized by place
   - If the breed has varieties, these are next
   - If a variety has subvarieties, these are next
2. List by groups and places with minimal structure.

   /group/place/(section/)?breed(/variety)?

   - The top level is group
   - Places go within groups
   - Sections are listed within places
   - Breeds are listed within their sections (whether or not they have a subsection)
   - If a breed has a variety, it is listed next
3. List groups for each place of origin

   /place/group/breed

   - Places first
   - Groups within places
   - Breeds within groups

**Options:**

- Something based on regular expressions, as above. This is appealing, but I'm not sure how to express "put this breed in a section if it has one, otherwise put it in the group that it belongs to" as opposed to "put this breed into its group, regardless of the section, if any".
- XPath 2.0 would be a possibility, but it would require me to enumerate all of the possibilities, like this for the first example:
  (/group|/group/section|/group/section/subsection)/place/(breed|breed/variety|breed/variety/subvariety)
  which seems inelegant. Consider if place were optional, for example...
- Something based on Linux/UNIX command line syntax:
  group[/section[/subsection]]/breed[/variety[/subvariety]]

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: My experience has been that when my relational data won't fit into a nice clear hierarchy, it's time to re-think my approach. Usually I end up realizing that I don't actually need the hierarchy. Is there some way you can solve your problem without using a hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

1. Some points about possible structures

a hierarchical structure can not really be imposed to a relational database (then data).

I try to put the differences:

- hierarchical is what you describe. It embarks parent and children. old databases used this concept.
- relational databases use a different concept: tables made of rows (one set of data) and columns (each component of the set), relations (same field between tables), and a query language to make selection, insert, update, delete: SQL. the force of SQL is his ability to do almost everything, it is a Standard, and every products are almost compatibles.

Then you can define a hierarchical structure with a relational database, but it is up to you (the database doesnt *know* your thinking).

For example: you can create relations like father/child:

Breed: name + index  + index of subsection + index of place

subsection: name + index + index of section

etc.

XPATH is not exactly a hierarchical structure, but a syntax to specify a path (for selecting) in a XML file.

**But, as you point it, XML defines a data structure of hierarchical type.**

2. About your needs

They are not totally defined.

I guess:

- you want to store datas
- you already have thought about hierarchy
- it seems like "read-only" datas: some dictionary, thesaurus, not an ERP :)
- quantity of datas are about hundred or thousands (dog breeds), not millions
- what about performance ? surely not very important
- what about store ? something to keep datas, and perhaps transfert them.

  3. With that, the easy solution can be an XML structure stored in one file

You will be able to store and move transport it.

You will be able to retrieve data with simple xpath, and the paths are easy to understand, and the file of every datas also.

But it is more difficult to modify it by code. If you have little modifications, better to do them by hand in the text file.

If you have multiple hierarchy, you must have several files.

hope it helps your work